# Not able to read Hive table using sparkR submit

Tags: apache-spark-sql, sparkr, spark-hive

Here is my Code:

```
 sc <- sparkR.init(master = "local[*]", sparkEnvir =  list(spark.driver.memory="8g"))
    hiveContext <- sparkRHive.init(sc) 
    sqlQuery <-  "SELECT * from table ABC"
    joinSQL <- sql(hiveContext,sqlQuery)
```

This is giving error while I am submiting using spark-submit sparkRscript.R

> Error:  a37fe9-9e5c-4569-879d-475944333fb0/_tmp_space.db
>
> **Error: Character input expected Execution halted** 18/09/16 23:33:29 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook

But While I am running on SparkR interactive shell Its working and giving expected result.